# How to work with SharePoint Roles Claim?

Tags: claims-based-auth, sharepoint-server, roles

I'm working with a Claims-base authentication and I'm wondering what kind of roles I can put for a Claim of the type:

http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI for a claim that specifies the role of a Windows user Admin,Manager or A list of all groups that the user is a member of . A claim as a piece of identity information (for example, name, e-mail address, age, or user role). The more claims your application receives, the more you know about your user. To understand more about the claims you need to understand the concept of identity provider and service provider .
Simple example :
Identity Provider "provider of the attributes" contains username,role attributes containing NikJan. A custom identity provider created by a hacker also contains an account with username attribute named NikJan. Both identity providers are making claims about a user. The consumer "SharePoint 2010" must choose which claim it's going to trust. SharePoint 2010 by itself will never trust either claim without being told to do so. In order for SharePoint to use a claim, it must first trust that claim which is setup by you the SharePoint administrator. If claims are trusted, then SharePoint can authenticate and authorize over that claim.Below are few claims supported

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddr
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn   userPrincipalName
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname 
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality  user
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role    sAMAccountName

Comment: Could you please provide some examples. What values I can use for this claim? How can I enumerate all user roles in this claim if a user has more then one role. Should I use comma, or just specify a separate role claim for every role?